# Angular/PHP Error de salida por pantalla

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero sacar por pantalla un listado de nombres. La petición se realiza correctamente, como se ve en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no se muestra por pantalla nada, por lo que intuyo que hay un error en los archivos del componente. Digo intuyo porque no aparece ningún error. Es más, ni siquiera sale por pantalla el mensaje que debería salir si no carga el listado. Añado los archivos a continuación:

- users.component.ts

```js
    import { Component } from "@angular/core";
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
    import { Users } from "../users";
    import { ApiService } from "../api.service";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-users',
      templateUrl: './users.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
      providers: [ApiService]
    })
    export class UsersComponent {
    
        public users: any;
        public user!: Users;
        //public confirmado:any;
        
        constructor(
            private _route: ActivatedRoute,
            private _router: Router,
            private _apiService: ApiService,
        ){}
    
        ngOnInit(){
            
            this.getUsers();
      
        }
    
        getUsers(){
            this._apiService.getUsers().subscribe(
                (result:any) => {
                    
                    if(result.code != 200){
                        console.log(result);
                    }else{
                        this.users = result.data;
                    }
                },
                (error:any) => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                }
            );
        }
    
        getUser() {
            this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
              let id = params['id'];
        
              this._apiService.getUser(id).subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                  if (response.code == 200) {
                    this.user = response.data;
                  } else {
                    this._router.navigate(['users']);
                  }
                },
                (error:any) => {
                  console.log(<any>error);
                }
              );
            });
          }
    }
```

- users.component.html

```html
<h3>Listado de empleados</h3>
                    <div *ngIf="users">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" *ngFor="let user of users">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption"> -->
                <h3>{{user?.name!}}</h3>
                <div>
                    <a [routerLink]="['user', user.id]" class="btn btn-md btn-primary">Ver</a>
             </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!users">
        Cargando listado de empleados...
    </div>
```

- Fragmento correspondiente en api.service.ts

```js
      getUsers(){
          return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/users.php');
        }
```

- Users.ts

```js
export class Users {
      public Id: number;
      public name: string;
      public pwd: string;
      public email: string;
      public hen_con: number;
      public minen_con: number;
      public hsal_con: number;
      public minsal_con: number;
    
      constructor(
        Id: number,
        name: string,
        pwd: string,
        email: string,
        hen_con: number,
        minen_con: number,
        hsal_con: number,
        minsal_con: number
      ) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.email = email;
        this.hen_con = hen_con;
        this.minen_con = minen_con;
        this.hsal_con = hsal_con;
        this.minsal_con = minsal_con;
      }
    }
```

He aplicado esta solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68615939/angular-error-ts2532-object-is-possibly-undefined pero no da resultado

Si es necesario algún archivo más, comentádmelo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado

**Actualización**: añado el código PHP por si fuera de ayuda

```
<?php
include_once("database.php");

//Lista de empleados
$sql = "SELECT name FROM empleados ORDER BY id ASC";
if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
}
```

**Actualización**: Consultando este link https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2 parece que el html no está mal, por lo que quizás el problema esté en cómo Angular y PHP están conectados

**SOLUCION**: El problema estaba aquí

```
(result:any) => {
                    
                    if(result.code != 200){
                        console.log(result);
                    }else{
                        this.users = result.data;
                    }
```

Retirando el condicional, el resultado aparece correctamente por pantalla

```
(result:any) => {  
                this.users = result;
            },
```

Comment: Es que hay diferencias: users es un componente que engloba a todos los usuarios, mientras que user sólo hace referencia a uno de ellos. De ahí que se utilice un ngFor para que salgan todos los empleados. Ahora, puede que esta diferenciación no la esté aplicando correctamente, por lo que agradecería que fueras más específico en tu solución o más ejemplificador. Con todo, cambiar en el html user por users tampoco arroja el listado

Comment: Es posible que estés teniendo problemas por llamar a tu variable `user` en el `ngFor`, puesto que ya tienes una variable `user` en la clase? (Y que además en este caso asumo está sin valor aún). Puedes probar a cambiarle el nombre a la variable del bucle por ejemplo `let usr of users`? O una simple `u`

Comment: He cambiado la variable del bucle y sigue sin salir nada por pantalla :/

Comment: No edites tu pregunta para añadir la respuesta... la respuesta va en la zona de respuestas (Puedes ponerla tú mismo). Nosotros no tenemos acceso a tu navegador, lo primero que debes hacer cuando te enfrentas a un problema es mirar qué carajo imprime en la consola el `console.log()` que acabas de poner!!!! La finalidad de poner `console.log(X)` es precisamente ver qué tienen las variables! Todo este rato tenía que estar poniéndote en consola el objeto `result`... habría bastado un vistazo para ver que no tiene un atributo llamado `code` (asumo que ese era el problema, vaya).

Answer (score -1):

Al parecer esta accesdiendo a una propiedad que no existe en la respuesta. puedes borrar esta parte [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cierto. Ya está arreglado, pero sigue sin aparecer nada por pantalla